# Entity framework power tools customization

Tags: entity-framework

I am reverse engineering code by using EF power tools. The problem is my Exsiting database has got more than one scehma's but i need to reverse engineer onl one of these. how can i customize it

Comment: I don't think it is possible with EF Power Tools.

Comment: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838 will include schema filtering in a future release.